# How to erase in sqlplus with backspace?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, sqlplus

Using SQL*PLUS, I cannot use the backspace button to erase content during a line command.

When I hit backspace, instead of erasing it writes ^H

Is there a way to configure backspace so it works as intended ?

Comment: Ctrl + backspace works okay for me, ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Linux/Unix, there's a way of making SQL*Plus loads friendlier on the command line - use `rlwrap`. It adds readline support to SQLPlus, allowing you to use the cursor keys to navigate to previous queries (it retains a history), and edit them when you've made a mistake.

Launch SQL*Plus with `rlwrap -i sqlplus` or add  `alias sqlplus="rlwrap -i sqlplus"` to your shell dot file (`.bashrc`/`.cshrc`/etc).

To install rlwrap on RHEL 5.0 use the following commands:

```
wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
yum install rlwrap
rlwrap –i sqlplus
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the following command in SQL*PLUS : `!stty erase <backspace>` but instead of the `<backspace>` statement, simply press the backspace button and hit return with what it gives you.

Comment: this works for me! No need to install another package.